# Replacing part of string while leaving the rest intact with Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, edit

I'm trying to edit a huge file with lines like:

```
1   9416    0   0   10  10  0   dropitems.drop_MFighter_m012_t91_u_m00          mfighter.MFighter_m201_t201_u               0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   icon.armor_t91_u_i00                    -1  7570    46  1   2531A298    0       1       21  1   Fighter.MFighter_m201_u             1   mfighter.MFighter_m201_t201_u               2   Fighter.MFighter_m201_hrh_ad00  104 114 Fighter.MFighter_m201_hrs_ad00  115 114                                                 2   MFighter.MFighter_m201_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MFighter.MFighter_m201_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Fighter.FFighter_m012_u             1   FFighter.FFighter_m012_t201_u               2   Fighter.FFighter_m012_hrr_ad00  114 114 Fighter.FFighter_m012_hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MFighter.MFighter_m201_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MFighter.MFighter_m201_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   DarkElf.MDarkElf_m010_u             1   MDarkElf.MDarkElf_m201_t201_u               2   DarkElf.MDarkElf_m010_Hrr_ad00  114 114 DarkElf.MDarkElf_m010_Hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MDarkElf.MDarkElf_m010_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MDarkElf.MDarkElf_m010_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   DarkElf.FDarkElf_m006_u             1   FDarkElf.FDarkElf_m006_t201_u               2   DarkElf.FDarkElf_m006_hrr_ad00  114 114 DarkElf.FDarkElf_m006_hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MDarkElf.MDarkElf_m010_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MDarkElf.MDarkElf_m010_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Dwarf.MDwarf_m008_u             1   MDwarf.MDwarf_m201_t201_u               2   Dwarf.MDwarf_m008_Hrr_ad00  114 114 Dwarf.MDwarf_m008_Hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MDwarf.MDwarf_m008_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MDwarf.MDwarf_m008_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Dwarf.FDwarf_m008_u             1   FDwarf.FDwarf_m008_t201_u               2   Dwarf.FDwarf_m008_hrr_ad00  114 114 Dwarf.FDwarf_m008_hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MDwarf.MDwarf_m008_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MDwarf.MDwarf_m008_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Elf.MElf_m011_u             1   MElf.MElf_m011_t201_u               2   Elf.MElf_m011_Hrr_ad00  114 114 Elf.MElf_m011_Hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MElf.MElf_m011_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MElf.MElf_m011_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Elf.FElf_m011_u             1   FElf.FElf_m011_t201_u               2   Elf.FElf_m011_hrr_ad00  114 114 Elf.FElf_m011_hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MElf.MElf_m011_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MElf.MElf_m011_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Magic.MMagic_m011_u             1   mMagic.MMagic_m011_t301_u               2       0   255 Magic.MMagic_m011_Rra_ad00  97  114                                                 2       Mmagic.Mmagic_m011_Rra_ad00_t301_x                      1   Magic.FMagic_m013_u             1   FMagic.FMagic_m013_t301_u               2       0   255 Magic.FMagic_m013_Rra_ad00  97  114                                                 2       Mmagic.Mmagic_m011_Rra_ad00_t301_x                      1   Orc.MOrc_m007_u             1   MOrc.MOrc_m201_t201_u               2   Orc.MOrc_m007_hrh_ad00  104 114 Orc.MOrc_m007_hrs_ad00  115 114                                                 2   MOrc.MOrc_m007_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MOrc.MOrc_m007_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Orc.FOrc_m007_u             1   FOrc.FOrc_m007_t201_u               2   Orc.FOrc_m007_hrr_ad00  114 114 Orc.FOrc_m007_hra_ad00  97  114                                                 2   MOrc.MOrc_m007_HRR_ad00_t201_a  MOrc.MOrc_m007_HRR_ad00_t201_a                      1   Shaman.MShaman_m007_u               1   MShaman.MShaman_m007_t301_u             2       0   255 Shaman.MShaman_m007_Rra_ad00    97  114                                                 2       MShaman.MShaman_m007_Rra_ad00_t301_x                        1   Shaman.FShaman_m007_u               1   FShaman.FShaman_m007_t301_u             2       0   255 Shaman.FShaman_m007_Rra_ad00    97  114                                                 2       MShaman.MShaman_m007_Rra_ad00_t301_x                        1   Kamael.mkamael_m005_u               2   MKamael.MKamael_m005_t101_u Mkamael.Mkamael_m005_t101_ut                3   Kamael.MKamael_m005_Lrr_ad00    114 114 Kamael.Mkamael_m000_w_ad00  119 95  Kamael.mkamael_m005_l_ad00  108 95                                      3   MKamael.MKamael_m005_Lrr_ad00_t101_a    Mkamael.Mkamael_m000_t00_w  Mkamael.Mkamael_m005_t101_ut                    1   Kamael.fkamael_m009_u               2   FKamael.FKamael_m009_t101_u FKamael.FKamael_m009_t101_ut                3   Kamael.FKamael_m009_Lrr_ad00    114 114 Kamael.Fkamael_m000_w_ad00  119 95  Kamael.Fkamael_m009_l_ad00  108 95                                      3   MKamael.MKamael_m005_Lrr_ad00_t101_a    Fkamael.Fkamael_m000_t00_w  FKamael.FKamael_m009_t101_ut                    1       1           0               0           LineageEffect.p_u002_a  4   ItemSound.armor_metal_alt_6 ItemSound.public_armor_04   ItemSound.shield_steel_1    ItemSound.shield_steel_8    ItemSound.itemdrop_armor_lightmetal ItemSound.itemequip_armor_lightmetal    1   0   2   5   0   226 0   0   36
```

I have come up with the following regular expression to find similar lines:

```
^.*?(_t91(.*?)1 0   2   5).*?$
```

Basically I have to change number 5 to number 6 and I'm trying to do so with the following regular expression:

```
\1t91\21    0   2   6
```

The result of that is a line starting in 't91' and ending as it should with the number replaced, but then it repeats itself 2-3 times (i.e: 2 6 0 226 0 0 36t91 etc.)

Do you guys have any ideas about this? Regular expressions are still a mystery to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to simplify the question or generalize it into a more readable example, otherwise it will be hard for people to help you.

Comment: Try `^(.*?_t91.*?1\s+0\s+2\s+)5(.*?)$` --> `\16\2` (or `${1}6${2}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you are trying to replace `5` as a whole word in a specific environment.

To match a whole word, you'd need `\b` (a word boundary) so as not to change a value like `55`.

To replace it just once on a whole line, you can use the regex

```
^(.*?_t91.*?1\s+0\s+2\s+)5(\b.*?)$
 |-----first group------|  | 2|
```

And replace with `${1}6${2}` (although `\16\2` works here, too).

If there are multiple values like this on a single line, use

```
(_t91.*?1\s+0\s+2\s+)5\b
```

And replace with `${1}6`.